Extract and replace pixel values based on their area or width
I have a segmented image as shown below
There is a very thin line of different colors on the edges of the vehicle (Red patch where the person is driving). I would like to get rid of this thin line by assigning different label ids (either red or black) based on the neighboring pixels. I know how to extract pixels based on the required color or even ids. But in this case, the color or ID is not fixed, it could be different colors or IDs in a different image. I am not able to come up with a way to extract just these pixels. Can someone help me with extracting pixels that belong to the thin line?

I presume you are referring to the cyan-coloured speckles? You say their colour is not known/fixed, but is the red colour known/fixed?

@MarkSetchell Yes, I am referring to the Cyan pixels. And since I am using segmented images it could be different object in another image so even Red color is not fixed. But the black on the other side is fixed as there is always a border to other objects. I am not able find a solution to detect these thin lines between objects.

Maybe you could dilate the black areas by a pixel or two?

A quick experiment with ImageMagick shows dilation with a 2-pixel disk-shaped structuring element clears all the cyan. I used magick YOURIMAGE.png \( +clone -fill white +opaque black -morphology erode disk:2 \) -compose darken -composite result.png

how come they're there in the first place? what does the color mean? the semantic segmentation output from your model is actually one mask per class, and this picture is a composite of all those. I would recommend that you reach in there, select the planes you care about, and work with those only.

you could select the red plane, dilate it, and reapply. or dilate, erase that from the picture, then readd the original plane.

@ChristophRackwitz These are not the results of the model instead these will be the input for the model. I am preparing the dataset for segmentation task. Each color indicates a class in an image and black region is the ignored region. While I combine masks for each classes based on the priority I end up with these thin lines between two objects. I don't want to use dilation on the image as I will loose information for other objects.

if you present the masks individually (as data, not illustration/screenshot/composite), then maybe I'll remember and show you what I mean.

Here's what I was alluding to in the comments. Select the black pixels, dilate them a little, then merge them back into original image:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv.imread('scene.png', cv.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Select black pixels
blacks = ( np.all(im == (0, 0, 0), axis=-1) * 255 ).astype(np.uint8)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-blacks-before.png', blacks)

# Dilate blacks with a circular structuring element
SE = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (4,4))
blacks = cv.morphologyEx(blacks, cv.MORPH_DILATE, SE)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-blacks-after.png', blacks)

# Select darker pixel at each location - the tilde (~) means the inverted image
res = np.minimum(im, ~blacks[..., np.newaxis])
cv.imwrite('result.png', res)



Here is an animation, alternating between the two debug images, showing how the dilation affects the blacks:


Notes:

Now you can see how dilation works, you can adapt it to Christoph's other suggestions.

The np.newaxis thing makes a [M,N] single colour channel array compatible with an [M,N,3] 3-colour channel array.

Make the structuring element larger to fatten the black lines even more, e.g. cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))



Thanks Mark for the suggestion. Unfortunately I cannot use Dilation here as I will loose information of other objects doing so. I will need these images for model training so I can't loose more information from them.

Maybe you can dilate the red areas, as suggested by Christoph. It's the same technique.

there might happen to not be black pixels near those stray ones, if the adjacent components happen to meet, right?

Ok, do the dilation of the black and get just the dilated part, not including the original black part. Then mask your original image with the dilated part, and run a findContours() over the image and remove any contours with a small area. Or, using the same dilated part, select each of your wanted colours and run a median filter on the intersection of the dilated part and your original image.
